# Automatic transcription YouTube - audio file not recognized; way to improve it

Tags: audio, youtube, transcription

When I upload an audio file (and an image together) on youtube, it does not recognize the words. The audio quality is that of a portable recorder; for me the words are enought clear. Is there a way to improve audio quality? I've already tried to do this with audacity, but the quality is worsened.
Thank you in advance.

P.S. I know that the transcriptions of youtube are inaccurate, but this is not a problem, the most important thing is to recognize the audio file.

Comment: Hard to tell without a sample. Could you upload one to show us what the quality sounds like?

Comment: Hi @slhck, I uploaded a file here (the beginning is full of noises): https://mega.nz/#!cV92UATQ!bn__kuXyauWZt7Y551tJj5OHXetY-pPe3UKCB8O2j9s

Comment: The recording isn't too bad, actually. YouTube's algorithm for detecting Italian may simply be not accurate enough. It may be even harder to use it on scientific material (which I presume this talk is about). Have you tried using a compressor effect (e.g. in Audacity) to bring out the speech more? What did you try with Audacity, actually?

Comment: Hi @slhck, I hear the word compressor for the first time. Could you help me to set this effect please?

Comment: See here: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/compressor.html — a compressor helps to make softer parts of the speech louder. Basically it "squeezes" the sound, which you can also hear if you apply too extreme settings. You may try playing around with the threshold (lowering it will increase the effect) and the ratio (higher ratio = higher compression). The speech should then be more audible, at least in the parts where it becomes too silent to detect otherwise.